# Lubuntu screen resolution on restart

Tags: lubuntu, display-resolution

I have installed Lubuntu 19 and my default resolution causes a part of the desktop to be eaten, I went to LxQt Settings > monitor settings and changed it but on restart the changes disapear. I read about this bug and a way to fix it but it was about the version 16 and there was an explicit x11/session.d folder in /etc where we needed to add a file but I can't find this folder now.

Comment: Can you please provide bug ID for the bug you read about and think is related. When in Monitor.Settings, did you click "Save" (*to save for future sessions*) or just hit "Apply" (*test the change but don't save for future*)?  https://manual.lubuntu.me/3/3.2/3.2.10/monitor_settings.html?highlight=monitor%20settings   Are you by chance using a TV as your monitor? as they have their own quirks (overscanning; where the tv is the problem and is tv specific).  Lubuntu also don't have a 19 release, I've assumed you mean 19.04.

Comment: Ok @guiverc I solved this by simply click on save after applying the resolution I needed. I frankly don't know what I have been doing to miss that even though I did try this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in Monitor.Settings, you can press

- "Save"     (*to save for future sessions*)

or

- "Apply" (*test the change but don't save for future*)

https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.10/monitor_settings.html

Comment: Manual links can change over time... as new features are added, the manual chapter/section parts change thus chapter 3, section 3.2, subsection 3.2.10 is correct for current *stable* release, but it was stale for prior 19.04 release answer was written for.